# How to give key more than one value in LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, graph

I have a graph, and i want to give each node different value, because i want to calculate every node's betweenness ,predecessor and so on,
but i think if i use map, the former value will be replaced. how can i figure out that ? Following is my code. I try to use map

```
  LinkedHashMap<Vertex<E>, Double> Betweenness = new LinkedHashMap<>();

  for(Vertex<E> vertex : graph.vertexSet())
  {
      Betweenness.put(vertex,0.0);            
  }

  for(Vertex<E> vertex : graph.vertexSet())
  {
      //Create stack to keep track of vertices in order to calculate value of flow
      StackADT<Vertex<E>> processingStack = new LinkedStack<Vertex<E>>();

      LinkedHashMap<Vertex<E> ,List<Vertex<E>>> Predecessor = new LinkedHashMap<>();

      for(Vertex<E> predecessorofVertex : graph.vertexSet())
      {
          List<Vertex<E>> PredecessorList = new LinkedList<>();
          Predecessor.put(predecessorofVertex, PredecessorList);
      } 
  }
```

Comment: You basically can't.  If you must have more than one value, your "value" is a List and you put multiple values in the List.

Comment: Create a LinkedHashMap containing Linked lists. Add values to the linked list and give it your choice key. When you iterate the map, each key will give you a list of values.

Comment: one of my value to that key is a empty list, how can I give that list to the LinkedList ?